# Menu in vuetify is wrongly offset to the right

Tags: vuejs2, vuetify.js

Trying to work with menus in vuetify, but my menu is wrongly offset to the right.

[image: Active menu is off to the right]

This is the code for populating the component:

```
<template>
  <v-container fluid grid-list-md>
    <v-layout row>
      <v-flex xs1></v-flex>
      <v-flex xs10>
        <v-layout class="background space-top" row wrap align-baseline>
          <v-flex xs4>
            <div class="header">IMAGE QUEUES</div>
          </v-flex>
          <v-flex xs4>
            <v-menu origin="center center"
                  transition="scale-transition"
                  bottom>
              <v-btn slot="activator" dark>Menu</v-btn>
              <v-list>
                <v-list-tile v-for="(item, i) in menuItems" :key="i" @click="">
                  <v-list-tile-title>{{ item.title }}</v-list-tile-title>
                </v-list-tile>
              </v-list>
            </v-menu>
          </v-flex>
        </v-layout row wrap>
          <v-layout class="background space-top" v-if="loaded" row wrap fill-height>
            <v-flex>
            </v-flex>
          </v-layout>
      </v-flex>
      <v-flex xs1></v-flex>
    </v-layout>
  </v-container>
</template>
```

Any clues or input is highly appreciated.

BR
Rune

Comment: Is your menu inside `v-app` component? Do you get any warnings or errors?

Comment: I missed the v-app requirement. Thanks a lot, Traxo. Please post it as an answer for me to accept it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrap your app inside [v-app](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/quick-start) component

> In order for your application to work properly, you must wrap it in
>   a v-app component. This component is used for dynamically managing your
>   content area and is the mounting point for many components.